# Main thread(ui thread) в android

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-threads

```
void play{
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait(100000);
                    tvv.setText("DONE");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
}
```

Есть данный участок кода. В данном случае если я запущу этот метод, он выполнится без проблем. Если я вызову его один раз он не вылетит и все будет хорошо. Он также не вылетит если я вызову его второй раз во время первого выполнения.

Вопрос следующий: Правильно ли я думаю, когда считаю что UI Thread после того как нем собралось задач больше чем некое число дает какое то время на решение, если его не последует вылезет диалог который сообщит что приложение не отвечает? Я экспериментально попытался это как то доказать себе, но лучше что бы кто то знающий развеял мои сомнения.

Comment: ответ на вопрос - да. если мейн тред тупит продолжительное время - система выдаёт диалог

Answer (score 0):

**ANR**

Когда UI поток приложения Android слишком долго заблокирован, вызывается ошибка «Application Not Responding» (ANR). Если приложение находится на переднем плане, система отображает диалог пользователю и дает пользователю возможность принудительно выйти из приложения.

ANR будет запущен:

1. Eсли activity находится на переднем плане, но приложение не ответило на событие или BroadcastReceiver (например, нажатия клавиш или события сенсорного экрана) в течение 5 секунд.
2. Несмотря на то, что у вас нет activity на переднем плане, ваш BroadcastReceiver не закончил выполнение в течение значительного периода времени.